# jquery not working when then view (component) loaded from another view (component) - angular 2 webpack

Tags: jquery, angular, angular2-routing

i have some jquery code in a js file. I have imported it in vendor.ts

Actually this jquery is working if I directly loads the page in browser by pasting the link. http://localhost:8085/#/history

But when I come from another component by clicking the link like below, jQuery is not working.
`<a href="#/history"> History</a>`

Is there any way out to make it work.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of using a routerlink? E.G. <a [routerLink]= "#/history">History</a>

Comment: routerLink is throwing error - Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:Parser Error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#/history]